# preventing div jumping on fadein

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery to fade in a caption on a icon mouseover.

```
$("#v1").mouseover(function() 
{
  $("#vc1").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Here is the `html`

```
<div class="preview_item" id="p1">
    <div class="view_site_caption" id="vc1">View Site...</div>
    <div class="view_site" id="v1"><a href="http://www.delicious.com" target="_blank"><img src="application.png" /></a></div>
    <div><img src="screens/001.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.view_site_caption
{
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:30px;
    display:none;
}
.view_site
{
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:30px;
}

.preview_item
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-600px;
    top:170px;
}
```

When the `mouseover` fires it works however the `<div><img src="screens/001.jpg /></div>`

Is pushed down. I want it to stay in place and the `view_site_caption` div to just fade in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that "div" an ID or Css class:

```
<div class="preview_item" id="p1">
    <div class="view_site_caption" id="vc1">View Site...</div>
    <div class="view_site" id="v1"><a href="http://www.delicious.com" target="_blank"><img src="application.png" /></a></div>
    <div id="donotmove"><img src="screens/001.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Style it with absolute positioning:

```
.preview_item
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-600px;
    top:170px;
}
#donotmove {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; //play with these numbers
    top:20px; //play with these numbers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want `#vc1` to take up the same space always, or if you want it to appear on top of the other stuff.

For the first option, remove `display:none;` and instead set `opacity` to `0`, and use `fadeTo("slow", 1)` for example.

For the second option, you probably want to use `position:absolute;` on `#vc1`, `position:relative;` on `#p1` so that you can position it within that `div`, then just add `bottom:0; left:0;` for example, if that's the point within `#p1` where you want `#vc1` to be placed.